# How to get the percentage of apt get output through regex?

Tags: regex, bash, apt-get, apt

Can someone please help me with a regular expression to get the percentage from the below bash output through regex?

```
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 libvlc$

Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 fonts-freefont-ttf$

40% [12 fonts-freefont-ttf 855 kB/4,140 kB 21%]
```

I just need to get the 40% from the above example..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 awk '$1 ~ /[[:digit:]]{1,3}%/ { print $1 }'
```

Check that the first delimited piece of the line pattern matches to 1-3 digits followed by a %. If it does, print the first piece.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
^\d{1,3}%
```

`^` - beginning of the line
`\d{1,3}` - one, two or three digits
`%` - percenatage sign

Demo: [regex101.com/r/tuyAbD/1](https://regex101.com/r/tuyAbD/1)

And if you want to have just number (without `%`) use this one:

```
^\d{1,3}(?=%)
```

Demo: [regex101.com/r/tuyAbD/2](https://regex101.com/r/tuyAbD/2)

Comment: @PS. I did upvote it shows that votes are recorded but wont be displayed for people with less than 15 reputation..

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` and `-p` :

```
grep -oP '^\d+%\s'
```